# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor" on google Charts

Tags: typescript, google-visualization

I am working in some charts using Google Charts and TS. I am getting errors like the one in the title. The charts sometimes work without any error, sometimes work correctly even with errors in the browser console...sometimes don´t work at all. Here its a little of my code.

```js
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/google.visualization/google.visualization.d.ts" />

Class Init{

CreateChart(): void{

            //call charts methods
            this.DrawActiveUsers();
            this.DrawExpensiveChart();
            this.DrawRequestsChart();
}

private DrawActiveUsers(): void{
 
        let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        ...
        ...
                let chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('topUsersChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
}
  
  
  private DrawExpensiveChart(): void {...}
  
  
  private DrawRequestsChart(): void {...}

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.min.css"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="google-chart/google-chart.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-progress/paper-progress.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let init = new Init();
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'bar'], "callback": init.CreateChart() });
        //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init.CreateChart());
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init.CreateChart()">
<div id="root">
    <paper-progress id="busy"></paper-progress>
    <paper-card id="top">
        <google-chart id="comboChart"></google-chart>
    </paper-card>
    <div id="bottom">
        <paper-card id="left">
            <google-chart id="expensiveChart"></google-chart>
            <div>
                <ul id="legend" class="content">
                    <li>
                        <p><span class="po"></span>Persistent Object (ms)
                        </p></li>
                    <li>
                        <p><span class="query"></span>Query (ms)
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </paper-card>
        <paper-card id="right">
            <google-chart id="topUsersChart">
            </google-chart>
        </paper-card>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea about how can i fix this?

Answer (score 4):

need to make sure google charts has loaded, before trying to use

**first**, the `'callback'` isn't defined properly in the `load` statement

the `'callback'` expects a reference to a function --> `init.CreateChart`

NOT the result of a function --> `init.CreateChart()`

as such, `load` statement should be...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'bar'],
  'callback': init.CreateChart
});`
```

**next**, the same function, also exists on the `body` tag

this will cause an issue, when `body` finishes before `google.load`

the google `'callback'` can also be relied upon to know when the page is ready

so no need for the inline event on `<body>`, remove it

Comment: Thanks for your help!! But still not working :(. Without the "onload" on body tag didn´t work at all :/

Comment: any errors in the console? and you changed the callback definition?